# How to Read/Render URLs Like Zend Framework

Tags: php, url, zend-framework, frameworks

I am working on creating my own framework in php.
Everything is going as planned except working the framework according to the URL.
 I cannot understand this:
Normal URL loading from `www.mydomain.com/folderone/foldertwo/index.php`
Zend Framework URL loading from the same URL would be
      `www.mydomain.com/folderone(controller)/folder2(action)/variables`

how can i create that logic?
What am i missing?
I am really dedicated to create this framework.

Comment: did u try looking at the Zend Framework source?

Comment: I did but i could not understand how it is being done in zend framework

Answer (score 2):

I had the same task as I setup my framework. This is a solution work for me.

Create first your .htaccess file. Set up your rewrite conditions and exclude your template path. You can do it like that (just copy & paste):

```
RewriteEngine On

Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index\.php -f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/template -d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index\.php?$1 [QSA]
```

Before I go ahead, we have to create five directories at least:

```
/var/www/models/
/var/www/controllers/
/var/www/classes/
/var/www/system/
/var/www/template/
```

Now, I added an auto loading in my index.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();

function autoload($class_name)
{
    $autoloadDirs = array('models', 'classes', 'controllers');

    foreach($autoloadDirs as $dir)
    {
        if(file_exists($dir.'/'.$class_name.'.php'))
        {
            require_once($dir.'/'.$class_name.'.php');
        }
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload');

require_once('system/Calling.php');

Calling::Run();

?>
```

At the script above you'll see that require_once within Calling.php

```
class Calling
{
    public static function Run($querystring = null)
    {
        //1. Parameter = Contollername
        //2. Parameter = Action
        $qString = preg_replace('/(\/$|^\/)/','',$querystring === null ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : $querystring);
        $callParam = !empty($qString) ? explode('/', $qString) : array();

        $controllerName = count($callParam) > 0 ?     (class_exists(ucfirst($callParam[0]).'Controller') ? ucfirst(array_shift($callParam)) : 'Error') : 'Main';
        //All controllers have suffix "Controller" -> NameController.php
        //and class name ike NameController
        //If no controller name given, use MainController.php
        $controllerClassName = $controllerName.'Controller';
        //All public methods have suffix "Action" -> myMethodAction
        //If there is no method named, use DefaultAction
        $actionName = count($callParam) > 0 && method_exists($controllerClassName, ucfirst($callParam[0]).'Action') ? ucfirst(array_shift($callParam)) : 'Default';
        $actionFunctionName = $actionName.'Action';

        //Fetch the params
        $param = new stdClass();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($callParam); $i += 2)
        {
            $param->{$callParam[$i]} = isset($callParam[$i + 1]) ? $callParam[$i+1] : null;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Init the Controller
        $controller = new $controllerClassName($controllerName, $actionName);
        $controller->$actionFunctionName($param);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //If you adapt this code: Is up to you to extends your controller  
        //from an internal controller which has the method Display(); 
        $controller->Display();
    }
}
```

Further, in your controller directory add your first controller namend MainController.php

```
//--> just better if you have also an internal controller with your global stuff 
//--> class MainController extends Controller
class MainController
{

    /** This is the default action
     * @param $params
     * @access public
     * @return
     */
    public function DefaultAction(stdClass $params)
    {
            //-> Do your staff here
    }

     /** This is the second action
     * @param $params
     * @access public
     * @return
     */
    public function SecondAction(stdClass $params)
    {
            //-> Do your staff here
    }

    /** This is the view handling method which has to run at least
     * and I recommend to set up an internal controller and to extend
     * all other controller from it and include this method in your
     * internal controller
     * @param
     * @access
     * @return
     */
    public function Display()
    {
        //-> Run your template here
    }
?>
```

Now, you can call the controller, methods and params like that:

```
//-> Load the main controller with default action
www.example.com/ 
//-> Load the main controller with default action
www.example.com/main/default/ 
//-> Load the main controller with second action
www.example.com/main/second/ 
//-> Load the main controller with second action and gives two params
www.example.com/main/second/key1/value1/key2/value2/
```

And now you'll have the following files and directories to start up your own framework.

```
/var/www/.htaccess
/var/www/index.php
/var/www/controllers/MainController.php
/var/www/system/Calling.php

/var/www/models/
/var/www/classes/
/var/www/template/
```

Enjoy your new basic framework kit

Answer (score 0):

Zend FrameWork and most MVC frameworks use a BootStrap.

It routes the URL (using .htaccess) to one file let's say (index.php) by using something like that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$ index.php
```

Which loads the bootstrap and the routing class that takes whatever data it needs from the URL.

According to ZEND manual:

> Routing is the process of taking a URI endpoint (that part of the URI
>   which comes after the base URL) and decomposing it into parameters to
>   determine which module, controller, and action of that controller
>   should receive the request. This values of the module, controller,
>   action and other parameters.
>   Routing occurs only once: when
>   the request is initially received and before the first controller is
>   dispatched.

EDIT: Answer for your comment:
Far away from ZEND FRAMEWORK, that's a code to test in a new PHP file:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://test.com/test1/test2/news.php';
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    $tokens = explode("/", $parse[path]);
    print_r($tokens);
?>
```

Comment: thanks, this makes sense to me and now i need to figure out how to turn the remaining of the url into variables after the domain name, How would i test this, can you recommend anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a router, you could look at [Glue PHP](http://gluephp.com/) for giving you examples.
It's a micro-framework that just do the routing part.